# Display custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using this code to display custom post type.

```
$gabquery = new WP_Query();
$gabquery->query('showposts='.$showpostbotleft.'&post_type=courses' );
```

How to edit it to limit number of posts and specific taxonomy name of this custom post type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using using the array form...

```
$gabquery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'courses',//The name of the post type
    'posts_per_page'=>5, //Use this rather than showposts
    'tax_query'=>array(
         array(
          'taxonomy'=>'my-custom-tax', //Your custom taxonomy name
          'operator' => 'IN',//NOT IN & AND also available
          'field'=>'slug',//or you could select by ID
          'terms'=>array('my-term-slug')//Get posts with this term (or ID if above is ID)
         )
    )
));
```

The above queries posts of type 'courses', limits the number of posts to be displayed to 5 per page, and selects only posts which belong to the 'my-term-slug' term of the 'my-custom-tax' taxonomy.

See the [WP_Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: It gives this error;Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ')'

Comment: Seems there's a slight error in the above code (a missing ')' somewhere...)

Comment: There was a missing comma, that may have been it. I've updated the code :D.